How to connect my local Node server with remote MYSQL db, via SSH and using sequelize
Im using Datagrip to manage the DB and all work just fine, i made the SSH connection then the DB connection and work perfect. im trying to do the same with my NODE server.
I got a virtual machine running my server, but i got the same server locally, and i want to start working with the live server in the local enviroment.
I was trying to make the connection, using tunnel-ssh and ssh2, but without luck, and there is almost non doc about it or its out of date.
